# Need clarification of one sentence in article

Tags: angularjs

I didn't understanding clearly, what means "zero function calls" in [this article](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/), in section "Resolve promises in router, defer controllers", in second paragraph. Can anyone who understood what there written about please describe the same but in other words.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the author is referring to the fact that you do not need to make any initialization function calls to fetch data for the controllers, as this part is solved by the resolves. This means the controllers load only after the data for them has become available beforehand.

As you can see in the example the author posted, the `SomeService.doSomething()` function call has been moved from the controller to the `config` section of the application.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest problem with the MVC architecture is "Controller bloat".

You want to keep your controller as lean as possible.

What the author explains is that by configuring the route in advance for that url, then your controller file does not need to contain a function call since it is catched by the routing listener before hand.

In truth there doesn't seem to be a real gain in efficiency since the call is made anyway but more in readability and code elegance.